# Can I check for an omitted HTTP request with Citrus framework?

Tags: integration-testing, simulation, citrus-framework

I have built a testsuite for a service orchestration with Citrus framework.

In one case, when the former request results in an "empty" response, the **last orchestration step, a HTTP request, is skipped**.

**How can I test that this last request is NOT executed?** I did not found a way to do this.

When I do not check this with an explicit expectation, the test is successful no matter if a request is executed or not.

I have an HTTP server simulation in place to respond according to the request. What I was looking for is something like

```
runner.http(action -> action.server(simulation)
    .receiveNothingDuring(5000)
);
```

to wait for 5 seconds for a request to arrive and SUCCEED if nothing arrives. This is kind of the inverse of the normal `receive` assertion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `receiveTimeout` action that is exactly what you need:

```java
runner.receiveTimeout(action -> action.endpoint(simulation)
                    .timeout(5000));
```

See also descriptions in [docs](https://citrusframework.org/citrus/reference/2.8.0/html/index.html#actions-receive-timeout)